# What is the correct noSQL collection structure for the following case?

Tags: mongodb, database-design, couchdb, database-schema, nosql

As someone who got used to thinking in relational terms, I am trying to get a grasp of thinking in the "noSQL way".

Assume the following scenario:

> We have a blog (eg. 9gag.com) with many posts and registered users. Every post can be liked by each user. We would like to build a recommendation engine, so we need to track:
>
> - all posts viewed by a user
> - all posts liked  by a user
>
> Posts have: title, body, category. Users have: username, password, email, other data.

In a relational DB we would have something like: `posts`, `users`, `posts_users_views (post_id, users_id, view_date)`, `posts_users_likes (post_id, user_id, like_date)`.

**Question**

What is the "right" structure would be in a document/column oriented noSQL database?

Clarification: *Should we save an array of all viewed/liked post ids in users (or user ids in posts)? If so, won't we have a problem with a row size getting huge?*

Comment: At least for MongoDB this has been discussed a zillion times.

Comment: @CRUSADER I presume you have some links for this specific scenario? This is actually quite a complex scenario (recommendation relations) so you should have some good links to share.

Comment: Discussed in every basic MongoDB tutorial

Comment: @CRUSADER Please provide a good link, it will help answer the question.

Comment: Google "Mongodb schema design"

Comment: @CRUSADER that's exactly why this question arose. Every MongoDB tutorial says that you have to save an array of viewed or liked post ids in a user (or visa-versa). Hence, my concern: there will be a lot of posts liked by a users and a lot of users who viewed and liked the post.

Comment: @CRUSADER That's not helpful.

Comment: How many users can you be expecting to like stuff? Could we be seeing you hitting the max document size?

Comment: This question is pointless and the answer depends very much on the underlaying database....so please ask a precise question instead asking vapor question that nobody can really answer in detail. The downvote was from me for exactly this reason.

Comment: @Sammaye we'll have a lot of post views. So yes, we'll exceed the row size. Even if we don't there will would experience issues while reading that row from the database because of its' size. So the question is, should we create an intermediate collections or is there another solution noSQL community uses?

Comment: The way I have personally done this with a video site is you house pre-aggregated statistical collections that are managed by my application. So I have a detail collection that will be used for per post stuff then I would do: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/use-cases/pre-aggregated-reports/ for the more complex stuff

Comment: @Sammaye thanks, that article helped. So, as far as the DB schema is concerned, for this specific case it suggests to build the structure the way queries would run most efficiently. OK, so there is no "right way" that community agreed upon.

Comment: exactly and yes this is still a grey area, there are threads 100 messages big on the topic in mongodb-user with arguments between each other on the best way, pre-aggregation and time buckets is the closest people have come to a standard response

Comment: There is no "NoSQL way" - each database technology has its own way of doing things.

Comment: @Philipp there is NoSQL way: "forget the relational way" ;)

Answer (score 0):

In CouchDB you could have separate documents for the user, post, view and like. Showing the views/likes by user can be arranged by the "view" (materialized map/reduce query) with map function emitting an array key `[user_id, post_id]`. As the result you will get the sorted dictionary (ordered lexicographically by the key), so taking all the views per `user='ID'` is the query with keys starting from `[ID]` to `[ID,{}]`. You can optimize it, but the basic solution is very simple.

In CouchDB [wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/) there is a comment on using [relationally modeled design](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/EntityRelationship) and [view collation](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/View_collation) mechanism (which can substitute some simple joins). To get some intuition I rather advice to study the problems of post and comments, which is also very simple, but not that much trivial as view and likes :)

There may be no NoSQL way, but I think most of the map/reduce systems share similar type of thinking. The CouchDB is a good tool to start, because it is very limited :) It is difficult to do any queries inefficient in distributed environment and its map and reduce query functions cannot have side effects (they are generating the materialized view, incrementally when the document set is changed, and the result should not depend on the order of document updates).